# Warning: Value was defined but never used; consider replacing with a boolean test

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have a function that is getting the following warning:

> Value intVal was defined but never used; consider replacing with a boolean test.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{
    text = (timerTxtFld.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    if let intVal = Int(text) {
        timerDoneBtn.alpha = 1
        timerDoneBtn.enabled = true
    } else {
        timerDoneBtn.enabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Could anyone help me work out what I need to do to get rid of the error?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error... All it is saying as that the value that you created (intVal) was not used. You can replace it with _ and it will silence the warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the let and do the comparison on the result of `Int` directly. You're creating `intVal` for no reason, and it's complaining that that's an unused variable.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{
    text = (timerTxtFld.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    if Int(text) != nil
    {
        timerDoneBtn.alpha = 1
        timerDoneBtn.enabled = true
    }
    else
    {
        timerDoneBtn.enabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: `if Int(text) { }` won't compile

Comment: Ooops forgot the value.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an error, it's a warning. The compiler is telling you that you created the const intVal but never used it.

Just change your if statement to

```
if Int(text) != nil
{

}
```